# Use a mergefield as data for a displaybarcode-field

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I am trying to use a mergefield in Word to populate the dataportion of a displaybarcode. In this case I am trying to set the employee-id as the data in a QR-code.

How I thought it should be done

```
{ MERGEFIELD EmployeeID \b OPERATOR: }
{ DISPLAYBARCODE "{ MERGEFIELD EmployeeID \b OPERATOR: }" QR \q 3 }
{ MERGEFIELD Name }
```

What I am trying to achieve is a list, with first the text "OPERATOR:" with the employeeID directly after. This row Works. Then I want to create a QR-code, containing the text in te row just above. This does not work. (It just creates the enitre text within the two '"'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By instead using the `{ MERGEBARCODE EmployeeID QR \q 3 }` I got the barcode to be based on the employeeID. I solved this issue by creating a new column in my Excel-file, containing the prefix i wanted.